# Stochastic Calculus - Ito decomposition

Tags: stochastic-calculus

I have got one question about Ito decomposition. Suppose $W_t$ is a Brownian Motion:

$X_t = W_t^2 + \int_0^t(W_t^3-1)du$

How to get $dX_t$? I am quited comfused by the integral. Should we calculate the integral first since it is just a normal integral. Or we take differential on both sides like:
$dX_t=dW_t^2+(W_t^3-1)du$ and use Ito's formula to calculate $dW_t^2$? If it is the latter case, why can't we do the integral first? If it is the former case, why can we do the differential first? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

By the very nature of paths of unbounded variation (such as those of Brownian motion), an expression such as $dW_t$ must be interpreted in integral form. In other words, when someone writes an expression of the form
$$dX_t = b dt + \sigma dW_t, \quad t \geqslant 0,$$
what they really mean is 
$$ X_t - X_0 = \int_0^t b ds + \int_0^t \sigma dW_s, \quad t\geqslant 0.$$
The differential notation is shorthand for the integral form and is defined to be the process $X_t$ which satisfies the integrated form in a suitable sense.

To answer your question, you can do either. That is, you can compute the integral $\int_0^t (W_s^3 - 1) ds$ directly, and then apply Itô's formula when applying the differential (as you must do with the $W_t^2$ term). However, if all you want is to write the process in differential form, there is no need to do this. Indeed,

\begin{align*}
d(X_t) &= d(W_t^2) + (W_t^3 - 1)dt \\
&= 2W_t dW_t + dt + (W_t^3 - 1)dt \\
&= 2W_t dW_t + W_t^3 dt.
\end{align*}
Again, in the above, the first equality only makes sense because
$$W_t^2 - W_0^2 = \int_0^t 2W_s dW_s + \int_0^t ds.$$

Comment: hi, then my question is how to compute the integral $\int _0^t(W_s^3-1)ds$?

Comment: @EEEEVannnnnn Define "compute the integral" for a random quantity.

Comment: @Did Would you mind giving a hint as to how to compute the variance of the mean zero Gaussian process $\int_0^t W_s^3 ds$ in a "simple" manner? (i.e., without going through the definition of the Riemann-Stieltjes integral)

Comment: (1) This is not a Gaussian process. (2) Indeed each such integral is centered since $E(W_s^3)=0$ for every $s$. (3) To compute the second moment, try $$E\left(\left(\int_0^tW_s^3ds\right)^2\right)=2\int_0^t\int_0^sE(W_u^3W_s^3)duds,$$ which reduces the problem to the computation of $E(W_u^3W_s^3)$ for every $u\lt s$ (which you might be able to complete by yourself).

Comment: Right, $W_s \rightarrow \int_0^t W_s^3 ds$ is not linear, my mistake. Thank you for (2) and (3). Do you then have any suggestions about how to identify the distribution of $\int_0^t W_s^3 ds$, or perhaps tell-tale signs of things to try when dealing with integrals or a Brownian Motion? Again, thanks for your time.

Comment: This would make for a nice m.se question. (Unrelated: Please use @.)

Comment: @Did Ah, thanks. Perhaps, but not so sure I did a great job: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1142932/identifying-distributions-of-integrated-stochastic-processes .

Answer (score -2):

X(t) = F(X,t) = X^2 + (X^3-1)t

Now you can use taylor expansion in terms of t and x and 1/2x^2 
thats it.

Comment: ..uh..thanks for your reply.....Maybe you should go over the stochastic calculus first...